# data modelling and queries in cassandra

Tags: database-design, cql, cassandra-2.0, nosql

```
   |ID|        Events        Timestamp  
   ----------------------------------------------
   |1 |       InProgress    2010-03-31 15:59:42
   |1 |       Awaiting      2010-04-31 15:59:42   
   |1 |       Resolved      2010-05-31 15:59:42
   |1 |       Closed        2010-06-31 15:59:42       
   |2 |       Awaiting      2010-07-31 15:59:42 
   |2 |       InProgress    2010-08-31 15:59:42   
   |2 |       Wait          2010-09-31 15:59:42         
   |2 |       Closed        2010-10-31 15:59:42
```

I have this table in Cassandra. From this table I need to extract two tables-one containing the 1st event corresponding to an ID and the other containing the  last event corresponding to an id.Thus, I should get two tables as my output:

```
    initial      
   -----------------------------   
   InProgress              
   Awaiting       

   final
   -----------------------------  
   Closed
```

I need to know as how can this be done in **cql(cassandra query language)only** or if there is a way that **I can model my data in such a way that I am able to obtain the desired results**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a schema like:

```
create table event(
    id int,
    ts timestamp,
    desc text,
    primary key (id, ts)
);
```

This will allow you to fetch by id and order by timestamp (asc or desc) and limit to 1.

However, check how many events per id you're expecting. If it's enough to take all events for an id beyond 100MB, you will need to start considering bucketing, or some other approach.

Another alternative is to use Spark to do the analytical query and store the result in a table that holds it in exactly the format you want. This does mean running an external job periodically (or a spark streaming app, that will be around a few seconds to minutes behind the live data), but it will work.

Comment: @ashic-My problem is that I have in total 7554 id's. So do I have to give the value of id everytime I need to get the 1st and last event, manually at the cql shell, or is there a way that I write a single query and get a table contaning the 1st event corresponding to every id and a table containing the last event corresponding to every id without specifying id in the WHERE clause

Comment: For 7400 ids, you can create a table like create table stats(shard int, id int, map<text, timestamp> minmax, primary key (dummy, id)). Be careful though...all the rows will be in the same partition, so if that grows, you will need to create new shards, and query two shard to get the values. On a separate note, why do you need 7K rows returned? Is that useful? Can it be solved in a different way (is that what the business actually needs?)? I'm recommending the shard approach as the query would be fast (hitting one partition). Querying all nodes would be terrible for perf & would likely timeout.